# How to get different output filename based on x86/x64

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-express, post-build-event

I am using VS2013 Express. I have my project setup to build in 32 or 64 bit, but I would like to get the .exe file when built, to include _32 or _64 depending on which platform I build for.

Not having any luck in the project properties.

Comment: This question is not as bad as it seems. The OP was looking at project properties because he thought there might be a property for that (there isn't). The answer was to use the post-build event, but how many developers don't know about post-build events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the following into your post-build box in the "Build Events" section of the project's properties:

> copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetName)_$(PlatformName)$(TargetExt)"

[image]

Comment: $(PlatformName) was the key! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2017